# Is it possible to track stolen Bitcoin after exchange

Tags: currencies, traceability, tracking, decentralized-exchanges

I don't know if someone can help me but I found out someone has stolen several times some crypto of me, mostly bitcoins. He had access to my computer and my phone to do the Google Authenticator because he is my IT guy.
I know who it is and everything is on police investigation but they can not do much on it at this moment.

So I would like to know if there is a possibility to track my Bitcoin transfers after they have been exchanged to another crypto.
When I look on the blockchain we just see 1 transfer and after this no trace anymore.
We already know he exchanged some Bitcoins to Ethereum, but how can we track or trace this exchange?
Is there a possibility to know which Crypto Wallet Company received my stolen Bitcoins?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can bitcoins be traced to scammers](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/83197/can-bitcoins-be-traced-to-scammers) OR [Can a Bitcoin address be traceable to a crypto exchange?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/101544/13866)

Comment: No this doesn't give an answer on my question. I found the transaction on the BlockChain but probably they exchanged the Bitcoins to Ethereum before they send it to an other wallet. How can I find a trace from the exchange from BTC to ETH??? Is it also possible to know to which wallet (Crypto wallet company) my BTC where send, so I can contact them.

Comment: My second link is to an answer which addresses your last question. Even if you could trace an exchange, the exchange may want proof before disclosing information relating to their customer's financial data - they might require a court order.

Comment: If tit stops after one transaction then it's probably not exchanged into Ethereum yet. Because you need one deposit transaction into an exchange and then you can see in the blockchain the consolidation of the coins into another address usually. I'd need more details why you think it's exchanged already into Ethereum

Answer (score 1):

> **I would like to know if there is a possibility to track my Bitcoin transfers after they have been exchanged to another crypto.**

There is always a possibility but it is generally beyond the capabilities and resources of a single victim. If you and other identifiable victims have lost the equivalent of millions of dollars then you may be able to get local police engaged. Otherwise you will need to spend large sums of money with blockchain analytics firms and gather evidence that can eventually be built into a legal case that can be used to compel exchanges to divulge confidential customer data. Legal costs may be substantial and involve lawyers in several jurisdictions.

Remember that cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin were designed to make this difficult. Services such as mixers were created to make it even harder. Following money through multiple cryptocurrencies will be harder still.

Answer (score 0):

There were several transfers from your wallet to the thiefs wallet(s). This would be the chance to catch the scammer:

1. All involved bitcoin addresses needs to be analysed to see if there are more addresses belonging with a high liklihood to the same scammer.
2. All outgoing transactions from each of the addresses of 1) needs to be traced if they end up in one of the millions of known exchange addresses
3. If there are evidences then the police should ask the exchange directly (or via help of their peers in the exchanges country) for any information about the scammer which is likely their client. This can be the id, bank account, a bitcoin withdrawal address or an altcoin withdrawal address. In the first two cases you can claim back the lost funds. In the last two cases this is the starting point for a new analysis/tracing

If someone moves bitcoin to an exchange then the follow on activities aren't visible in the blockchain anymore, then the exchanges support is needed.

To be more specific I'd need to see the bitcoin address(es) where the coins went to after leaving your wallet.

Comment: I know the thief(s) transfered BTC to another wallet. This is one of the links: 18yQvmCvGH7MvmwzH4uagfa3n7VyoL76f4 from the BTC transactions. But how can I see those BTC are exchanged to another crypto? How can I see to which wallet my BTC were send?

Comment: This address received 0.00137400 BTC it's not at an exchange yet. When the bitcoin find its way to an exchange then only the exchange can tell you (or the police) what happened then. So if their client exchanged the bitocoib into Monero then the exchange has it in their books (this isn't visible in the bitcoin blockchain).

Comment: So if the thief exchanged this amount of BTC in other crypto I can not track it further? He already admitted to the police that he changed the bitcoins to other crypto but I don't have details at this moment.

Comment: If he admitted then I wouldn't care about this anymore. Nobody can make the thiefs transactions unhappen. You only can claim the stolen value back. Nevertheless where the funds are now, if the thief is known you need to claim it back with help of police or a lawyer.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how much he has stolen from my wallet in total and maybe other people. That's why I try to find as much information to trace it.

Comment: Do you know how many bitcoin you purchased in total and how many is left in the wallet? Then you would know what is missing. Each wallet has a history where you can see all transfers in and out. There I'd start. And if he doesn't admit it then tracing for all suspicious outgoing transactions would be the next step

Comment: I'm listing up the suspicious outgoing transactions but with this I still don't know how I can find to which wallet company my Bitcoins where send and I can not find the exchange transactions between Bitcoin and Ethereum on the other wallet. Is there a possibility to find it out?

Comment: May be. But I'd not purely concentrate on the flow of your coins, you have much more chances to find evidences if you follow the thief. E.g. if the thief owns bitcoin address A then analytics might find out that addresses B,C and D belong as well with high likelyhood to the same person. And often it's easier to trace one of those coins.

Comment: You need evidences who stole the coins and it's not important where the coins are now. The bitcoin transaction cannot be reverted you can only catch the thief and claim back what you lost. Starting point for this is one or more bitcoin addresses of the thief. I understand if you don't want to publish it here. Just want to point out how the tracing works.

Comment: I know who stole the coins but we don't know how much he has stolen. Maybe he also maid other victimes and that's why I'm looking how I can find back all transactions. We only have 1 bitcoin address from thief and he only received Bitcoins on it. That's why we think I directly exchanged them for other crypto or for withdrawal. So my question is how can I find the exchange transaction without having access to the wallet where the exchange has been done?

Comment: Without the wallet I have only one idea (which is less precisely): Analystics needs to be done from the one known address to find other addresses belonging very likely to the same person.