# How do I find out where my bitcoins got sent to?

Tags: transactions, blockchain, wallet, address

I withdrew bitcoin from my account in Binance in 2018 and still have the email they sent with address it said it sent to,18bVuA2FxDdz5gE4qf9MgbsNxp2F46PaLD
The time and amount looked correct. Now I don't remember if it was a wallet or to another account. Blockchain.com says the current value is 0. But I didn't do anything to it. How can I find out what happened to the bitcoin amount and where it was sent to? Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can a Bitcoin address be traceable to a crypto exchange?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/101544/can-a-bitcoin-address-be-traceable-to-a-crypto-exchange)

Comment: Just use the "blockchain explorer" to search for that address.